# Unable to modify Scheduled Task Windows 2008 SP2

Tags: windows, scheduled-task

Issue:
The server is a VM on vCenter, OS is Windows 2008 SP2.
There is no performance issue.
Everything is fine except, unable to modify Scheduled Task.
We can create a new Scheduled task, but once created we cannot modify it (Like change the schedule time to run)

Troubleshooting Done.

1. I compared other servers in the series (Same Config, Same Application), all settings are same
2. Server is in same OU as rest of working server
3. Reboot performed.
4. Tried login with Domain Admin, same issue
5. Tried login with Local Administrator account same issue.

It just errors saying the "The task cannot be performed"

Any more troubleshooting ideas please. The application jobs time needs to be changed but cannot change due this error.

Comment: I don't know what's happening here, but can you not just deleted the old task and create a new one with the correct time?